# How to reset the admin password for Datastax Opscenter?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

How can I reset the admin password in Datastax Opscenter? Will disabling and reenabling authentication in /etc/opscenter/opscenterd.conf do the trick? Will I lose any other data in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was fairly simple. All I needed to do was stop OpsCenter, rename (or remove) passwd.db, and restart OpsCenter again. The daemon automatically creates a new password db file and sets the admin password to 'admin'.

Comment: Good solution!  I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: But How to update if I want set a customised password?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an official way to simply reset the admin password in OpsCenter.  However, I do know of a "hacky" way to do it, if you're up for that (and if you have physical or ssh access to the server).

OpsCenter's user authentication is maintained in a SQLite database file named `passwd.db`, located in the root of your OpsCenter directory.  The file is created once you enable user authentication in OpsCenter.  Using sqlite3, you can open and manage this file:

```
$ sqlite3 passwd.db 
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(users);
0|id|INTEGER|0||1
1|username|TEXT|0||0
2|password|TEXT|0||0
3|groupid|INTEGER|0||0

sqlite> SELECT * FROM users;
1|admin|8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918|1
```

Looking above, you can see the row for the "admin" user of a brand new install of OpsCenter 5.2.1 is the hash of:

> 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918

If you update the password field on the users table to that value, it *should* reset it back to the original:

```
UPDATE users
SET password='8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918'
WHERE username='admin';
```

I don't know if the passwords on different versions of OpsCenter use the same hash or not, but this should work if you're using OpsCenter 5.2.1.  Otherwise, if you have a user in there that you *do* know the password to, you can (look up and) set the admin password to *that* hash, and then at least you'll know the password and be able to log in.

Comment: BTW- I'm almost positive that DataStax support would not approve of this method, so use at your own risk.

Comment: That's a clever idea, and I almost went with it, but since we didn't need to keep any of the other user IDs on the system all I needed to do to reset the admin username was remove the passwd.db file.